# Eureca.io start: Where is eureca.js?

Tags: javascript

The docs for [Eureca.io](http://eureca.io/) (which looks very cool) have an example with the client side line:

```
<script src="/eureca.js"></script>
```

Looks very normal. But there is no script called "eureca.js" installed with npm install eureca.io. What/Where is this file? Does it masquerade by another name? I'm mystified.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies installed with NPM are by default placed in the `node_modules` folder.  Look there for a `eureca.io` subfolder and in there you should find `lib/EurecaClient.js`.  Not sure why the example just includes `eureca.js` from the root folder... :/

*Disclaimer:  I haven't actually tried using this.*

Answer (score 0):

Actually, eureca.js is generated dynamically no need to put it anywhere in your project, just reference it in your  tag as you did above, and run the server script.